# How do you select items in a listbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do you programmatically select items in a multi-select listbox using jQuery?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var valToSelect = "1";
$("#mySelect option[value='" + valToSelect + "']").attr("selected", "true");
```

Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyAHr/

Just for kicks, here's an alternative example if it fits the situation:

```
var values = $("select").val();
values.push("1");
$("select").val(values);
```

​Here's a quick example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/FBRFY/

This second approach takes advantage of the fact that [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on a **multiple** `<select>` element returns an array, not a string.  You can get it, add or remove any values, then set it again using `.val()` and it'll be updated with the new selection.

Comment: @Nick Craver - what if i only have the value (not the display).  lets say bob is the display and value is 1

Comment: @oo - This works in that case, one moment I'll update with an example.

Comment: @NickCraver Bro in second line of code Comma's after True is really messing things around.

Comment: @NickCraver - You missed a " " around true.  Ill edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

In ListBox that have multi selection mode use it :

```
  $('#ListBox1').find('option:selected').map(function () {
  alert($(this).text());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasListItems = $('#ddlListItems option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.text).join();
```